# Convert Seq[Option[Map[String, Any]]] to Option[Map[String, Any]]

Tags: scala

How to Convert `Seq[Option[Map[String, Any]]]` to `Option[Map[String, Any]]`

So skip any option that is None, and keep the valid Maps and merge them. If every option is None, then the final option should be None as well.

Answer (score 1):

A `flatMap` along with `groupMapReduce`, followed by an Option `filter` should do the job:

```
val listOfMaps: List[Option[Map[String, Any]]] =
  List(Some(Map("a"->"p", "b"->2)), None, Some(Map("a"->"q", "c"->"r")))

val mergedMap = listOfMaps.
  flatMap(_.getOrElse(Map.empty[String, Any])).
  groupMapReduce(_._1)(t => List[Any](t._2))(_ ::: _)
// mergedMap: Map[String, List[Any]] = 
//   Map("a" -> List("p", "q"), "b" -> List(2), "c" -> List("r"))

Option(mergedMap).filter(_.nonEmpty)
// res1: Option[Map[String, List[Any]]] =
//   Some(Map("a" -> List("p", "q"), "b" -> List(2), "c" -> List("r")))
```

A few notes:

1. [`groupMapReduce`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.0/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#groupMapReduce[K,B](key:A=%3EK)(f:A=%3EB)(reduce:(B,B)=%3EB):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,B]) is available only on Scala `2.13`+.
2. If you must stick to `Seq` instead of `List`, simply replace method `:::` with `++` in `groupMapReduce`.
3. It is assumed that merging of the Maps means aggregating the Map values of a common key into a List.  Replace `groupMapReduce` with `toMap` if keeping only one of the Map values of a common key is wanted instead.
4. This solution treats `Some(Map(.empty[String, Any]))` the same as `None`.

Comment: after flatMap, can we just to toMap? e.g., listOfMap.
  flatMap(_.getOrElse(Map.empty[String, Any])).toMap

Comment: @Jing Huang, yes you could, if what you meant by merging is to keep only one of the values from multiple `key->value`s with common key.  With the above sample data, `mergedMap` would become `Map("a"->"q", "b"->2, "c"->"r")` (i.e. `"a"->"p"` would be gone).

Comment: This is not correct. This will return `None` for `List(Some(Map.empty[String, Any]))` when it should return `Some(Map())`

Comment: @Tim, I think differentiating `None` vs `Some(Map())` or not is just some trivial requirement details the OP could clarify and adjust (e.g. keeping/skipping the Option `filter`) if necessary.

Comment: @LeoC The requirement is actually pretty clear that you only get `None` when every `Option` is `None`. I also don't think it is a trivial change, so perhaps you could  update your answer to give that solution as well?

Comment: @Tim, no, it's not really clear as that isn't a `only if` condition, but you're right that the necessary change for treating `None` vs `Some(Map())` differently is indeed not as trivial as flipping the Option `filter` using my approach.  I've added a note to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is a one-line solution

```
val in: Seq[Option[Map[String, Any]]] = ???

val out: Option[Map[String, Any]] =
  in.flatten.headOption.map(_ => in.flatten.reduce(_ ++ _))
```

The `in.flatten.headOption` is a simple way of getting `Some` if at least one of the elements is `Some` or `None` if they are all `None`.

The `reduce` just combines all the `Map`s into one.

This can clearly be optimised by avoiding the duplicate `in.flatten` call.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with `flatten`,`fold`, `++` and a match at the end to provide `Some` or `None`.

**baz.scala**

```scala
package baz
object baz {
  // fixtures
  val x0 = Seq[Option[Map[String, Any]]]()
  val x1 = Seq[Option[Map[String, Any]]](None)
  val x2 = Seq[Option[Map[String, Any]]](Some(Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> "two")))
  val x3 = Seq[Option[Map[String, Any]]](Some(Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> "two")), Some(Map("c" -> 3.0)), None)

  def f(x: Seq[Option[Map[String, Any]]]) =
    x.flatten.fold(Map[String, Any]())((a,b) => a ++ b) match { case m if m.isEmpty => None case m => Some(m) }
}
```

Sample run

```
bash-3.2$ scalac baz.scala && scala -classpath .
Welcome to Scala 2.13.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_66).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import baz.baz._
import baz.baz._

scala> x0 -> f(x0)
res0: (Seq[Option[Map[String,Any]]], Option[Map[String,Any]]) = (List(),None)

scala> x1 -> f(x1)
res1: (Seq[Option[Map[String,Any]]], Option[Map[String,Any]]) = (List(None),None)

scala> x2 -> f(x2)
res2: (Seq[Option[Map[String,Any]]], Option[Map[String,Any]]) = (List(Some(Map(a -> 1, b -> two))),Some(Map(a -> 1, b -> two)))

scala> x3 -> f(x3)
res3: (Seq[Option[Map[String,Any]]], Option[Map[String,Any]]) = (List(Some(Map(a -> 1, b -> two)), Some(Map(c -> 3.0)), None),Some(Map(a -> 1, b -> two, c -> 3.0)))

scala> :quit
```